# Square root of complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

Real numbers usually have more than one square root, but when we write sqrt(x), we mean the principal square root of x.

What about complex numbers? What root are we referring to when we write sqrt(a+bi)?

Comment: Short answer: It depends – but a common convention is the one with argument in $(-\pi,\pi]$. Longer answer: Learn about [branch cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts). Even longer answer: Learn about Riemann surfaces.

Comment: I don't think there is any simple convention as well established as the $\sqrt5$ convention. Mathematica tends to give $\sqrt(a+ib)$ with positive real part.

Comment: I've always liked discarding the negative real axis, then taking the root with imaginary part the same sign as the original.

Comment: Correction to my earlier comment: I was thinking of the argument of the argument (sorry, pun not intended but unavoidable), which then becomes halved, leaving the argument of the square root in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.